# Objective-C: issues in setting up boolean value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Consider this `json`

```
{
            "amount": "60.81",
            "category": "Utilities",
            "debit": true,
            "name": "Comcast",
            "date": "Sat, 02 Aug 2014 14:36:46 -0000",
            "uuid": "112c43eb-6e5e-4b4d-9079-6d896fa11b01"
        }
```

I have a `TransactionModel` class which looks like

**TransactionModel.h**

```
@interface TransactionModel : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *uuid;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *amount;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *category;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL *debit;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *date;

- (TransactionModel *) initWithDictionary: (NSDictionary *) dictionary;
@end
```

and in **TransactionalModel.m**, I do the following

```
@implementation TransactionModel

    - (TransactionModel *)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {
        TransactionModel *transactionModel = [[TransactionModel alloc] init];
        transactionModel.uuid = [dictionary valueForKey:@"uuid"];
        transactionModel.name = [dictionary valueForKey:@"name"];
        transactionModel.amount = [dictionary valueForKey:@"amount"];
        transactionModel.debit = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"debit"] boolValue];
        transactionModel.category = [dictionary valueForKey:@"category"];
        transactionModel.date = [dictionary valueForKey:@"date"];
        return transactionModel;
    }
    @end
```

I am using `AppCode` and it warns on line

```
transactionModel.debit = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"debit"] boolValue];
```

as

```
Taking pointer from integer without a cast
```

[image]

is it not the right way to set `boolean` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL debit;` NOT `@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL *debit;`.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `BOOL *debit;`, which means pointer to a `BOOL`

Change it to `BOOL debit;`

Answer (score 1):

`@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL *debit;` should not have an asterisk (*)